# Datastage: set web server trasformer stage url from query

Tags: datastage

I need to set "PortAddress" and "WSDL Address" dinamically using the result of a query.

I've created the oracle Connector stage with my query. For example:

```
select col1,col2,col3,...,url
from myTable
```

How can I use "url" column value in the Web Service stage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem not restricted to your web service transformer. You want to "transfer" data from a data stream to the Sequence level in order to feed it into the next job as a parameter.
Basically there are two main ways to do it:

1. Parallel Edition: In the first job where select the url from your database and write it to a value file of a parameter set. Use the parameter set in the second job with the new value file. Details see [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21610390)
2. Server Edition: In a server job you select the data from your database in a transformer you can use a DataStage function (DSSetUserStatus) to set the so called UserStatus for this job. This can then be referenced in the next job of the Sequence.